# System tray isn't showing in Dash to Panel

Tags: gnome, 18.04, system-tray, menu-bar

I have a ubuntu `18.04` and configured `dash to panel` in it, also I've added the `Applications Menu` extension, to show me some categories.

It's beautiful and it's working smoothly, but I don't have a system tray anymore, some programs that I use, like `Steam` and `Google Chrome` (for chrome apps) are better accessed through the system tray icon.

Could you please show me the way to configure it, or to install/configure another taskbar with a category menu that might have the system tray?

Sorry but I dislike the the default menu that show everything at once (dash?), also I'm not fond of having two bars, one at the side and one at the top.

Comment: Dash to Panel should work nicely with appindicators. Check whether the Ubuntu Appindicators extension is active. Eventually, turn it of then on again. Also log out then back in before deciding it does not work. If it does not work, try disabling it and try another extension designed to show legacy tray icons.

Comment: I've noticed the same issue with KeePassX. App Indicators doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Did the Steam tray icon actually not showing **or** it shows an icon but not showing a menu when clicked?

If the tray icon is showing but its menu not showing when clicked, then try configure **Dash to Panel** (via Gnome Tweak Tool) to move the panel to **TOP**. I hope this is the case.